# Generic lambda with std::function does not capture variables

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14

I'm trying to use the generic lambda of C++14, but got a trouble with std::function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    const int a = 2;
    std::function<void(int)> f = [&](auto b) { std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl; };
    f(3);
}
```

This fails to compile with an error message saying that `error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope`.

It works if I change it to `(int b)`.

Is it a bug? or am I missing something?

The version of GCC i'm using is 4.9.2.

Comment: clang accepts it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a00425d68054e75

Comment: Try without `const`, see what happens? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772867/lambda-capture-as-const-reference

Comment: @Caramiriel yeah [without `const`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c48476442dc9bfc9)

Comment: @Caramiriel: Dropping `const`, explicitly naming `a`, changing `auto` to `int` or moving to clang++ all make it work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I can reproduce this unless I do any of the following:

- remove `const` from `a`
- name `a` in the *capture-list*
- change `std::function<void(int)>` to `auto`
- make the lambda non-generic by changing `auto b` to `int b`
- use Clang (e.g. v3.5.0)

I believe that this is a compiler bug related to optimisations and a failure to detect *odr-use* in a generic lambda (though it's interesting that setting `-O0` has no effect). It could be related to [bug 61814](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61814) but I don't think it's *quite* the same thing, therefore:

**I have raised it as [GCC bug 64791](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64791).**

- *(Update: this bug has since been marked as fixed in GCC 5.0.)*

Certainly I can't find anything obvious in the C++14 wording that should disallow your code, though there's very little "obvious" in general in the new C++14 wording. :(

---

> `[C++14: 5.1.2/6]:` *[..]* For a generic lambda with no lambda-capture, the closure type has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function template to pointer to function. The conversion function template has the same invented *template-parameter-list*, and the pointer to function has the same parameter types, as the function call operator template. *[..]*
>
> `[C++14: 5.1.2/12]:` A *lambda-expression* with an associated *capture-default* that does not explicitly capture this or a variable with automatic storage duration (this excludes any *id-expression* that has been found to refer to an *init-capture*'s associated non-static data member), is said to implicitly capture the entity (i.e., `this` or a variable) if the *compound-statement*:
>
> - odr-uses (3.2) the entity, or
> - names the entity in a potentially-evaluated expression (3.2) where the enclosing full-expression depends on a generic lambda parameter declared within the reaching scope of the *lambda-expression*.
>
> *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> void f(int, const int (&)[2] = {}) { } // #1
> void f(const int&, const int (&)[1]) { } // #2
> void test() {
>   const int x = 17;
>   auto g = [](auto a) {
>     f(x); // OK: calls #1, does not capture x
>   };
>
>   auto g2 = [=](auto a) {
>     int selector[sizeof(a) == 1 ? 1 : 2]{};
>     f(x, selector); // OK: is a dependent expression, so captures x
>   };
> }
> ```
>
> *—end example ]* All such implicitly captured entities shall be declared within the reaching scope of the lambda expression. *[ Note:* The implicit capture of an entity by a nested lambda-expression can cause its implicit capture by the containing lambda-expression (see below). Implicit *odr-uses* of this can result in implicit capture. *—end note ]*
>
> `[C++14: 5.1.2/13]:` An entity is captured if it is captured explicitly or implicitly. An entity captured by a *lambda-expression* is odr-used (3.2) in the scope containing the *lambda-expression*. *[..]*

Comment: I'm not getting #1. The lambda doesn't odr-use `x`, so why is `x` still implicitly captured?

Comment: @templateboy: `[&]` is a _capture-default_, though you may be right about the lack of odr-use, actually.

Comment: In [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04d9eb2d5966270f) example `x` is not odr-used (and doesn't satisfy the other condition) so I find it weird that it's still captured.

Comment: This no longer reproduces on trunk: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8SxSYJayF2nkBN7M

Comment: @T.C. Why does it only work when `a` is `const`? Also, I don't see why the original example doesn't compile when he's using `&` as the capture default. Doesn't `&` means he captures `a` as well?

Comment: I overlooked the fact that the OP used `&` as a capture default. Now I'm not sure why it wasn't captured. I expect `&` to capture everything whether or not it's a generic lambda.

Comment: FYI this has been marked [fixed in GCC 5.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64791#c10).

Answer (score 3):

```
int main() {
    const int a = 2;
    auto f = [&](auto b) { std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl; };
    f(3);
}
```

Don't know if it should work with `std::function` but this works for sure.

Further investigation:

I created a class to mimic as closely as possible the lambda:

```
class Functor {
private:
  int const x;

public:
  Functor() : x{24} {}
  auto operator()(int b) const -> void { cout << x << " " << b << endl; }
};


std::function<auto(int)->void> f2 = Functor{};
f2(3); // <- this works
```

This suggests that your example should have worked. After all lambdas are the same in behavior with an object who has the `operator()` overloaded and fields for the captured variables.

If we change the class to get to the `auto` part:

This doesn't work:

```
class Functor {
private:
  int const x;

public:
  Functor() : x{24} {}
  auto operator()(auto b) const -> void { cout << x << " " << b << endl; }
};

std::function<auto(int)->void> f2 = Functor{}; // <-- doesn't work
```

However this works:

```
class Functor {
private:
  int const x;

public:
  Functor() : x{24} {}
  template <class T>
  auto operator()(T b) const -> void { cout << x << " " << b << endl; }
};

std::function<auto(int)->void> f2 = Functor{}; // <-- this works
```

So most likely it is related to the use of `auto` as parameter of lambda/functions, a feature new to C++14 so most likely without a mature implementation.