# how is this lambda with an empty capture list able to refer to reaching-scope name?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, language-lawyer

In the C++14 standard § 5.1.2/12 it shows an example of a lambda expression that apparently seems to be able to refer to a reaching scope's variable `x`, even though:

1. the capture list is empty, i.e. no capture-default
2. the comment says that it "does not capture `x`"

Here's the example:

```
void f(int, const int (&)[2] = {}) { } // #1
void test() {
  const int x = 17;
  auto g = [](auto a) {
    f(x); // OK: calls #1, does not capture x
  };
}
```

See that it [does compile](https://ideone.com/eglPPs). It seems to hinge on `x` being `const`; if the `const` is removed, it no longer compiles for the reasons one would expect (capture list is empty). It happens even if I make the parameter be `int` so that it's no longer a generic lambda.

How is it possible for the lambda to refer to `x` even though the capture list is empty? And how is this possible while at the same time apparently *not* capturing `x` (as the comment says)?

The closest thing I found on this subject was someone else tangentially [noticing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141403/generic-lambda-with-stdfunction-does-not-capture-variables#comment44655433_28141551) this in a comment.

Here's the full section 5.1.2/12 from the standard:

> A *lambda-expression* with an associated *capture-default* that does not explicitly capture `this` or a variable with automatic storage duration (this excludes any *id-expression* that has been found to refer to an *init-capture*’s associated non-static data member), is said to *implicitly capture* the entity (i.e., `this` or a variable) if the *compound-statement*:
>
> - odr-uses (3.2) the entity, or
> - names the entity in a potentially-evaluated expression (3.2) where the enclosing full-expression depends on a generic lambda parameter declared within the reaching scope of the *lambda-expression*.
>
> [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> void f(int, const int (&)[2] = {}) { } // #1
> void f(const int&, const int (&)[1]) { } // #2
> void test() {
>   const int x = 17;
>   auto g = [](auto a) {
>     f(x); // OK: calls #1, does not capture x
>   };
>
>   auto g2 = [=](auto a) {
>     int selector[sizeof(a) == 1 ? 1 : 2]{};
>     f(x, selector); // OK: is a dependent expression, so captures x
>   };
> }
> ```
>
> —*end example* ] All such implicitly captured entities shall be declared within the reaching scope of the lambda expression. [ *Note*: The implicit capture of an entity by a nested *lambda-expression* can cause its implicit capture by the containing *lambda-expression* (see below). Implicit odr-uses of this can result in implicit capture. —*end note* ]

Comment: The short explanation I believe is the compiler performs [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) and all uses of "x" are replaced with the actual value.

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks. It was something I was considering but I wasn't aware of the rules of that in C++ to know for sure. I'm inclined to believe that this is the practical effect of the rule Barry quoted.

Comment: Pretty much, and when you use `&` you are taking its address, so the compiler needs to allocate storage space for the variable.

Comment: @JesseGood That makes perfect sense. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Related to [Understanding the example on lvalue-to-rvalue conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28506342/1708801)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have the right quote. A variable needs to be captured if it is *odr-used*. [ODR-use](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) means basically that the variable is used in a context where it needs a definition. So either its address is taken, or a reference is taken to it, etc. One key exception is, from [basic.def.odr]:

> A variable `x` whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression `ex` is *odr-used* by `ex` **unless applying
>   the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) to `x` yields a constant expression (5.20)** that does not invoke any nontrivial
>   functions and, if `x` is an object, `ex` is an element of the set of potential results of an expression `e`, where either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to e, or e is a discarded-value expression (Clause
>   5).

So in your example, applying lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `x` yields a constant expression (since `x` is a constant integral), so it's not odr-used. Since it's not odr-used, it doesn't have to be captured.

On the other hand, if `x` were bound to a reference (e.g. `f` took its argument as `const int&`), then it *would* be odr-used, and so would have to be captured. In the second example presented, `x`'s "odr-use-ness" is *dependent* on what the generic lambda argument is, so that is considered captured anyway for sanity's sake.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up! Is this essentially describing what enables constant folding, which Jesse commented about on my question?

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña Basically. If it's a constant, you only need to capture it as such if it's used in a context where it would need to exist as an object.