# C++ and C++11 class static member, double should use "constexpr" while int can be "const", why?

Tags: c++, c++11, static, double, constants

A structure C defined several static const members like this:

Code is like below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct C{
    static int i;
    static const int j=1;
    static constexpr double d=1;
    static const double d1=1.0;
};
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation will lead to error:

```
$g++ testStatic.cpp -std=c++11
testStatic.cpp:6:25: error: in-class initializer for static data member of
      type 'const double' requires 'constexpr' specifier
      [-Wstatic-float-init]
    static const double d1=1.0;
                        ^  ~~~
testStatic.cpp:6:5: note: add 'constexpr'
    static const double d1=1.0;
    ^
    constexpr
1 error generated.
```

Why so weird
Why static int can be const，double should be constexpr，what's the rational

Comment: Integral constant expressions have always been special in C++. Basically, they are the kinds of values you can reason about without having to consider platform-dependent details, and they're the kinds of values you can use as (non-type) template arguments.

Comment: Read [Constant expression initializer for static class member of type double](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30742473/1708801) you will find a lot of background there. See also [Why type const double is not captured by lambda from reaching-scope, but const int is?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34362729/1708801) which is somewhat related.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const` follows the original language specification defined in C++98 and C++03. It was generally disallowed to supply an in-class initalizers for `static const` members in C++98. The possibility to do so for `static const` objects of integral and enum types in C++98 was part of *special treatment* given to these types.

`constexpr`is a new feature introduced in C++11. It is designed differently and works uniformly for all types.

So, you can just use `constexpr` for both integer and floating point types and forget about any non-uniformities.

If you continue to use `const` in such contexts, you will have to deal with C++98 legacy. However, C++17 will introduce *inline variables*, which should also make it possible to use in-class initializers for `inline static const` objects of any type.