# Access to constexpr variable inside lambda expression without capturing

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr

In the following example, I can access the `constexpr` variable `x` from inside the lambda `y` without explicitly capturing it. This is not possible if `x` is not declared as `constexpr`.

Are there special rules that apply to `constexpr` for capturing?

```
int foo(auto l) {
    // OK
    constexpr auto x = l();
    auto y = []{return x;};
    return y();

    // NOK
    // auto x2 = l();
    // auto y2 = []{ return x2; };
    // return y2();        
}

auto l2 = []{return 3;};

int main() {
    foo(l2);
}
```

Comment: Fascinated to know why the down-vote.  This looks an intriguing corner of the standard to me, and a few minutes googling didn't find the answer.

Comment: I edited the question because it took me quite some time reading the question to understand why the non-constexpr declaration of `x` was marked `NOK`, and I didn't understand until I read the answer. Hopefully this makes it clearer. If you disagree, feel free to roll back.

Comment: Sometimes it is hard to ask a question in a straightforward way, if you don't know the anser yet. Thank you for clearifying the question!

Comment: There are a couple of interesting cases wrt to constexpr, see [Understanding the example on lvalue-to-rvalue conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28506342/1708801)

Comment: This would also work for [constant integral but not const floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34323489/1708801)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Are there special rules that apply to `constexpr` for capturing/accessing?

Yes, `constexpr` variables could be read without capturing in [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Explanation):

> A lambda expression can read the value of a variable without capturing
>   it if the variable
>
> - has const non-volatile integral or enumeration type and has been initialized with a constant expression, or
> - is constexpr and trivially copy constructible.