# g++ won't allow generalized capture of const object by reference in lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

This is rejected by g++ (4.9.3 and 5.2.0), but is accepted by clang 3.5.0:

```
int main() { 
    const int ci = 0;
    auto lambda = [ &cap = ci ]() { };
}
```

g++ gives `error: binding ‘const int’ to reference of type ‘int&’ discards qualifiers`. It appears that g++ refuses to allow non-const references to be captured, except of course using plain old C++11 capture `[&ci]`. That seems a very strange constraint, perhaps a bug in g++?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772867/lambda-capture-as-const-reference

Comment: @CoryKramer, that question is indeed very closely related. I commented on that question today also. I guess my question here is: "given a *const* object, how can I capture it by reference?". Whereas that question is "given a *non-const* object, how can I capture it by const reference?". I guess a good answer would cover both these questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is valid. §5.1.2/11 goes

> An *init-capture* behaves **as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable of the form 
> “`auto` *init-capture* `;`”** whose declarative region is the *lambda-expression*’s *compound-statement* […]

Now, clearly, declaring

```
auto &cap = ci;
```

and capturing `cap` is fine. That is,

```
int main() { 
    const int ci = 0;
    auto &cap = ci;
    auto lambda = [&cap]() { };
}
```

[compiles with GCC](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Yh1Nyx4hnrNMspNe). Apart from the declarative region and lifetime of `cap`, there is no difference between this snippet and yours, thus GCC is incorrect.
This bug has already been reported as [**#66735**](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66735), with a similar example:

```
int x = 0;
auto l = [&rx = static_cast<const int&>(x)] {};
```

Comment: In that case, I'll report it soon. I'm extremely surprised that this bug wasn't noticed before - it seems to be such a simple example. Surely I'm not the first person to have tried to capture const objects by reference?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid You aren't, but capturing a `const` object by reference using an init-capture is probably happening very rarely.

Comment: [This report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66735) is very similar. I might just comment on that bug with my slightly simpler example.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Thanks. I'll incorporate that into the answer.

Comment: I found this while trying to capture a non-const object by const, by first const-casting it to const. But yes, capturing an object that is already const (i.e. my quesion here) would be very strange!

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I've come across this in several contexts. E.g. trying to "drill into" a const reference parameter to a function in a lambda. E.g. `f(const Sprite& sprite)`. Lambda `[&rect = sprite.m_area]`, and, worse, any attempt to capture a member variable in a const member function.

Answer (score 4):

This looks similar to [gcc bug: [C++14] lambda init-capture fails for const references](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66735) which says:

> This code fails to compile:
>
> ```
> int main() {
>     int x = 0;
>     auto l = [&rx = static_cast<const int&>(x)]() {};
> }
> ```
>
> The error message is:
>
> > test.cpp:3:14: error: binding 'const int' to reference of type 'int&'
> >     discards qualifiers
> >
> > ```
> > auto l = [&rx = static_cast<const int&>(x)]() {
> > ```
>
> But according to [expr.prim.lambda]/11 rx should be captured as auto
>   &rx = static_cast(x), that is as const int&.

the bug report references *[expr.prim.lambda]/11* which says:

> An init-capture behaves as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable of the form “auto init-capture ;”
>   whose declarative region is the lambda-expression’s compound-statement, except that[...]