# How do I capture some (but not all) member variables of a class with C++ lambda

Tags: c++

The following dummy example may not really make sense in real world. But it explains the question. I have a `class Foo` with members `firstname` and `lastname`. The function `ForEachMessage` takes a lambda. I want it to capture only the `firstname` of `Foo` but not `lastname`. How do I achieve that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

vector<string> messagesList;
void ForEachMessage(function<void(const string&)>callBack)
{
    for (const auto& str : messagesList) {
        callBack(str);
    }
}

class Foo {
public:
    std::string firstname;
    std::string lastname;
    void say() {
        ForEachMessage([this](const std::string& someMessage)
        {
            cout << firstname << ": " <<  someMessage << endl;
        });

        // Error: firstname in capture list doesn't name a variable
        // ForEachMessage([firstname](const std::string& someMessage)
        // {
        //    cout << firstname << ": " <<  someMessage << endl;
        // });

        // Error: expect ',' or ']' in lambda capture list
        // ForEachMessage([this->firstname](const std::string& someMessage)
        // {
        //    cout << firstname << ": " <<  someMessage << endl;
        // });
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Foo foo;
    foo.firstname = "Yuchen";
    foo.lastname = "Zhong";
    messagesList.push_back("Hello, World!");
    messagesList.push_back("Byebye, World!");
    foo.say();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is the least useful problem description in the world.

Comment: @molbdnilo, thanks for the comments. I added the error message as well.

Comment: [Quick fix](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/131b92770d94e458). Wonder if there's a better way though.

Comment: For what it's worth, cherry-picking variables is probably not worth the effort. The compiler can figure things out pretty well and shouldn't capture variables not used by the lambda.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, this is interesting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the C++14 named capture for this:

```
ForEachMessage([bla=firstname](const std::string& someMessage)
    {
        cout << bla << ": " <<  someMessage << endl;
    });
```

(See it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b857f780294c597f)) To avoid a copy, you may also capture by reference with `[&bla=firstname]` instead. For a discussion on how to capture by `const&`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772867/lambda-capture-as-const-reference) and in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32440415/3002139).

(Remark: The local name can, but need not be different from the member name.)

Comment: Looks like you could even use `[&firstname=firstname]`

Comment: @SimonKraemer Indeed, you beat my edit by seconds. Thx for the input.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I just tested if it's possible to make the reference `const` to avoid it being altered within the lambda. `[&firstname=static_cast<const string&>(firstname)]` does the job.

Answer (score 3):

Create a reference to `firstname`

```
const std::string& rfn = firstname;
```

And capture the reference

```
ForEachMessage([rfn](const std::string& someMessage)
{
  cout << rfn << ": " << someMessage << endl;
}
```

Comment: Oops. Thanks for fixing mine. M(