# VC++ 15 calls the wrong copy constructor for lambda capture?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda, clang, copy-constructor

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
struct X {
  X () = default;
  X (X &) { std::cout << "non-const called" << std::endl; }
  X (X const &) { std::cout << "const called" << std::endl; }
  int i () const { return 7; }
};

auto f () {
  X x;
  auto lambda = [=]() { return x.i(); };
  return lambda;
}

int main()
{
  auto lambda = f();
  std::cout << lambda () << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

With VC++15, I get the output

```
const called
const called
7
```

With Clang 3.9, I get

```
non-const called
7
```

Which compiler is correct here?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772867/lambda-capture-as-const-reference) may be of your interest. To be straight I don't think your question is a duplicate :)

Comment: It's worth noting that with optimizations enabled, VC also applies RVO resulting in only one call to `X(X const&)`.

Comment: @skypjack: Are you sure lambdas construct a const member? http://ideone.com/RQ7OjC I think the data members are not necessarily const, only `operator ()` is.

Comment: @JohnB Fair enough. I'm correcting the answer too. Good catch.

Comment: @Oktalist still the call should be to `X(X &)`, right?

Comment: @skypjack As far as I know, right.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that clang is right.
The most suited constructor is called only once when the lambda captures `x` and the constructor for the returned value is optimized out.
That's why you obtain only one *non-const called*.

---

See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) for further details about copy-elision and RVO.