# Should we capture by const reference in lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, closures, c++14, constants

I have been reading [Lambda capture as const reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772867/lambda-capture-as-const-reference)
It is an interesting feature, and sometimes I also wish this feature to exist, especially when I have huge data, which I need to access inside a lambda function.

My follow up questions -

- Should we capture by const reference in lambda? If yes, how should it be behave?
  (Edit - I am also interested in the behaviour of the lifetime of the captured variable.)
- **Is there any possible downside, by introducing it in the C++ grammar?** (I can't think of any)

Let us assume we can.
We assume `[const &]` as syntax to capture.

```
int x = 10;
auto lambda = [const & x](){ std::cout << x << std::endl; }; 
lambda(); // prints 10, great, as expected

x = 11;
lambda(); // should it print 11 or 10 ?
```

My intuition is that is should behave just like `[&]` but the captured value should not be allowed to modify.

```
template<typename Func>
void higher_order_function(int & x, Func f)
{
    f(); // should print 11
    x = 12;
    f(); // should print 12
}

void foo()
{
    int x = 10;
    auto c = [const & x] () { std::cout << x << std::endl; };

    c(); // should print 10
    x = 11;
    c(); // should print 11
    higher_order_function(x, c);

    auto d = [const & x] () { x = 13; }; // Compiler ERROR: Tried to assign to const qualified type 'const int &'!
}
```

Comment: You are making a common mistake with the meaning of `const`.  `const` doesn't describe a value -- only a particular symbol.  It **does not** mean "the value won't change".  It means "this particular symbol won't change the value"

Comment: When trying to compile (clang++ -std=c++14) I get this error: `expected variable name or 'this' in lambda capture list`. How can I compile this? (I removed the last statement).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been wondering about this myself.
Since the operator() is const by default, I would assume that allowing const references is acceptable as well.

With the current standards(C++17), the closest I got to this behaviour is:

```
auto c = [ &x = std::as_const(x) ] () { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
```

Workaround in C++11/C++14 would be(thanks to Daniel for suggestion):

```
auto const & crx = x;
auto c = [ &crx ] () { std::cout << crx << std::endl; };
```

Comment: Just a note, this is valid from C++17. In C++11, you can alternatively do `const int & crx = x;` and capture `crx` then instead of `x`.

Answer (score 4):

```
lambda(); // should it print 11 or 10 ?
```

I don't understand why it should print 10. Consider `lambda` being just an instance of some anonymous class. Making it a normal class, it should look like:

```
class Lambda {
   public:
      Lambda(const int & i) : i_(i) { }
      void operator()() { std::cout << i_ << std::endl; }
   private:
      const int & i_;
 };

int x = 10;
Lambda lambda(x);
lambda(); // prints 10, great, as expected

x = 11;
lambda(); // should it print 11 or 10 ?
```

The meaning of const reference here is only that you cannot modify `x` through `i_` member reference variable.

---

A simlpler scenario:

```
int x = 10;
const int & crx = x;
x++;
std::cout << crx << std::endl; // prints 11
```

Comment: The question was, if there should be a language extension.

Comment: @kiloalphaindia It was not exacly clear for me what OP is asking, since there are multiple questions. `// should it print 11 or 10 ?` this is a question as well.

Comment: @DanielLangr, thanks for the explanation. I am more interested in "Is there any possible downside, by introducing it in the C++ grammar?". Any comments or insight on this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for but... I suppose you can pass through a function that receive the same value by const reference.

Something as follows

```
template <typename T>
auto make_capture_const (T const & x)
 { return [&x](){ std::cout << x << std::endl; }; }

// ...

int x { 42 };

auto l = make_capture_const(x);

l();
```

If you try to modify `x` inside the lambda

```
std::cout << x++ << std::endl;
```

you should get an error.

As you can see, from, this solution you get that `x` can't be modified inside the lambda but the lambda is influenced from the value changes outside

```
   int x { 42 };

   auto l = make_capture_const(x);

   l();  // print 42

   x = 43;

   l();  // print 43
```

IMHO, an hypothetic `[const &]` capture syntax should works in the same way. But I understand that is highly questionable.

Comment: In C++17, you can also use `auto lambda = [&x = std::as_const(x)]{ std::cout << x << std::endl; };`.

Comment: @DanielLangr - interesting; I did't know it.

Comment: @max66 , thanks for the explanation. I am more interested in "Is there any possible downside, by introducing it in the C++ grammar?". Any comments or insight on this?

Comment: I guess the downside is that the lambda can't be passed out of the function scope if it captures by reference. If you don't need to modify the values, why restrict the portability?