# Passing this pointer and arguments of class method to local lambda function at compile time

Tags: c++, class, lambda, constexpr, compile-time

Suppose you have a scenario when you want to create a `constexpr` lambda inside a method for calculating something at compile time.

```
struct A {
    int a;
    constexpr A(int a) : a(a) {}
    constexpr auto operator+(const A& rhs) {
        constexpr auto l = [&]() {
            return A(this->a + rhs.a);
        };
        return l();
    }
};
```

This code doesn't compile because compiler said that `this` and `rhs` are not constant expressions. Is there a way for passing `this` and `rhs` to a local `constexpr` lambda?

Comment: What is the point of using the lambda at all? Why not just `constexpr auto operator+(const A& rhs) { return a + rhs.a; }`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Perhaps the posted code is just a *minimal* example of what is being sought? In OP's 'real-world' code, there may be a more justifiably reason to want a lambda.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Adrian. It is just a minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't **capture** the `a` members of `this` and `rhs` (by reference) and maintain `constexpr` validity<sup>1</sup>; however, you *can* pass those members as *by (const) reference* arguments to your lambda:

```cpp
struct A {
    int a;
    constexpr A(int a) : a(a) { }
    constexpr auto operator+(const A rhs) {
        constexpr auto l = [](const int& ta, const int& ra) {
            return A(ta + ra);
        };
        return l(a, rhs.a); // Or return l(this->a, rhs.a) if you prefer
    }
};
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Or *maybe you can*, but it's messy: [Lambda capture as const reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3772867/10871073)