# Passing attributes from this pointer and object arguments of class method to local constexpr lambda function and use the returned result

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, constexpr, compile-time

This is follow-on from the post: [Passing this pointer and arguments of class method to local lambda function at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69005795/10871073).

Suppose that you want to use the result array of local `constexpr` lambda inside a `constexpr` method:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct A {
    std::array<T, N> arr;
    constexpr A(std::array<T, N> arr) : arr(arr) {}
    constexpr auto operator+(A rhs) const {
        constexpr auto l = [](const auto& ta, const auto& ra) {
            std::array<T, N> result;
            result.fill(T{0});
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                result[i] = ta[i] + ra[i];
            }
            return A(result);
        };
        constexpr auto result = l(arr, rhs.arr);
        /* use result by calling another constexpr methods / functions */
        return result;
    }
};

template<typename ... T>
A(T...) -> A<T..., sizeof...(T)>;

int main() {
    constexpr A a(std::array<int, 3>{1, 2, 3}), 
    constexpr A b(std::array<int ,3>{4, 5, 6});
    constexpr A c = a + b;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler said that `this` and `rhs` are not constant expressions. How can I maintain constexpr-ness in this case?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR;** Do not declare local variables `constexpr` in already `constexpr` functions.

Slight misunderstanding about how `constexpr` works.

`constexpr` functions are evaluated at compile-time only when used in compile-time context + as-if rule of course.

But defining `result` as `constexpr` means it must be `constexpr` even when the enclosing function is called in run-time context. That of course cannot be achieved, hence the error. One should use `constexpr` for local variables only if its "constness" is independent of the "constness" of the enclosing function.

### `constexpr` in lambdas

This is little bit more tricky, see [C++ usage of constexpr with lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64713512/c-usage-of-constexpr-with-lambda-expression) for more general details.

By binding the lambda into `constexpr auto l`, the initialiation of the lambda object must be `constexpr`, that is trivial and can only be broken by non-trivial capturing  - e.g. by non-constexpr copy.

Lambdas' `operator()` are implicitly `constexpr` if possible. So there is no need to use `[](const auto& ta, const auto& ra) constexpr {}`, but it would result in a compiler error if the body could not be `constexpr` for some reason regardless of the outer function. This is similar version to making `result` `constexpr`.

Comment: Ok, but there's a way to achieve this without lambda? Maybe with another constexpr method / function? @quimby

Comment: @apopa Sure, the lambda is not needed at all, [this](https://godbolt.org/z/dKEr8c7dv) works too. Not the `std::move`, you should use it because it will use move ctors of `T` to copy the arrays around.

Comment: What if I want to use the result_array as an argument of a constexpr method? https://godbolt.org/z/4qca6YaKf

Comment: See the code in compile explorer above. Basically that array need to be returned from a constexpr function / method. @quimby

Comment: @apopa Then what you want is impossible. Image the function is run at run-time, the value would not be known at compile-time and the function must be compilable in both contexts. Perhaps you want `consteval`?

Comment: Can you show me an example with consteval? @quimby

Comment: @apopa The goal is to use `zeros` in some `constexpr` context right?

Comment: @apopa Hnnm, I tried but I cannot make it compile even with `consteval`, I do not have much experience in this aspect, perhaps try to ask a new question with the posted code from godbolt please?

Comment: Yes, I'll do that, thank you for your time! :) @quimby

Comment: @apopa No problem :) Sorry for not getting you the right answer.